# XMLHttpRequest to a HTTPS URL with a self-signed certificate

Tags: https, xmlhttprequest, ssl-certificate

How to do a Javascript XMLHttpRequest to a https:// URL using a self-signed certificate, that is known by the client to be legit?

My attempts fire the error event of XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: If anyone came here developing chrome extensions: I found [this google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/adA6Asn1QC4) while googling, for anyone that turns up here. I'm going to just add the certificate to the trusted store on my machine while testing. Also take a look at [this chrome.* api **for chrome OS only**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_platformKeys), or the [dev chrome.* api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/platformKeys).

Comment: @ehmicky, I need the same thing, did you resolve it?

Comment: @Subha, this was 4 years ago, but I do not think I did

Comment: @ehmicky, thanks for responding

Comment: No one have a solution for this yet?

Comment: I'm only making this comment based on the fact that no answer was provided.  Assuming that it's not possible, it would be very easy to get a legit certificate using LetsEncrypt - https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore self signed certificate in XmlHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685016/how-to-ignore-self-signed-certificate-in-xmlhttprequest)